# How to do multi core programming in F#

Tags: f#, multicore

How do I program I F# that utilize multi cores CPU? Say instead of multithread or async? In python language, they have multiprocessing module but what is the equivalent for F#?

Comment: One option is [Async.Parallel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.parallel%5B't%5D-method-%5Bfsharp%5D). I've also had some success with using [Parallel Sequences](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq).

Comment: You do utilize multiple cores from a single process when you use async or regular .NET multithreading. So the premise of this question seems off to me.

Comment: Just as Mark Seeman says above. And [Nessos Streams](http://nessos.github.io/Streams/) has examples of PSeq. There is also PLinq, and there is also Parallel in C#. Can you show an example what you would like to parallelize?

Answer (score 3):

There are several approaches for parallelization in `F#`

1. `F#` uses `CLR` and `CTS` so it is possible to use usual .NET
   constructions like you do it in `C#`. For example: `Thread`,
   `BackgroundWorker`, `AutoResetEvent` etc. [Details](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-async-and-parallel/)
2. `F#` has a built-in construct called "asynchronous workflows"
   [Details](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-async-and-parallel/)
3. There are some frameworks which allow you to choose appropriate
   parallelisation model. For example [Hopac](https://github.com/Hopac/Hopac)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a couple of pointers to what has already been mentioned in the comments:

- Have a look at [this blog post by Don Syme](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsyme/2010/01/09/async-and-parallel-design-patterns-in-f-parallelizing-cpu-and-io-computations/) which covers the basics of async
- Or look at [this blog post by Tomas Petricek](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-parallel-plinq.aspx/) with examples of parallel `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

If You're intereseted in GPU programming (which is strongly related to multicore, or even [manycore](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37982/what-is-the-difference-between-many-core-and-multi-core)) in F#, take a look into [Alea GPU](http://www.aleagpu.com/release/3_0_2/doc/) which allows You to easily use F# for technologies like CUDA.

For list other GPU programming options in F#, look [here](http://fsharp.org/use/gpu/).

You can also try to employ the actor model. [Akka.NET](http://getakka.net/) has some nice F# API.

There's also an [incoming book](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-concurrency-in-dotnet) that as a whole can be considered an answer to the question (didn't read it yet).